# How to use DISTINCT keyword in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How to use `DISTINCT` keyword in SQL Server? I mean if it can work for given field.

```
select id, name, age 
from dbo.XXX
```

There are multiple row returned by the query. I would like to get how many kinds of id or name or age.

`select **distinct** id, name, age from dbo.XXX` or
`select id, **distinct** name, age from dbo.XXX` or
`select id, name, **distinct** age from dbo.XXX`

To sum up, I would like to use a single SQL to get the distinct count of each fields, like `select  id,  name,  age from dbo.XXX`

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Why is this a question? You have identified 3 variations of code you can try. Try all 3 of them your self and then see if they return what you want. IF not return with a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dense_Rank can be used to calculate a distinct count for any column and multiple columns:

```
Select col1, col2, col3,
    dense_rank() over (partition by [col1] order by [Unique ID]) + dense_rank() over (partition by [col1] order by [Unique ID] desc) - 1 as DistCountCol1,
    dense_rank() over (partition by [col2] order by [Unique ID]) + dense_rank() over (partition by [col2] order by [Unique ID] desc) - 1 as DistCountCol2,
    dense_rank() over (partition by [col3] order by [Unique ID]) + dense_rank() over (partition by [col3] order by [Unique ID] desc) - 1 as DistCountCol3
from [table]
```

Comment: @Julian Updated to demo multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ID
from dbo.XXX

Select distinct name
from dbo.XXX

Select distinct age
from dbo.XXX
```

If you want to know how many rows you have for each distinct ID or Name or Age, you can use the following:

```
Select ID, count(id) as [ID_Recurrence]
from dbo.XXX
group by ID

Select Age, count(age) as [Age_Recurrence]
from dbo.XXX
group by Age

Select Name, count(name) as [Name_Recurrence]
from dbo.XXX
group by Name
```

Comment: Thanks.It looks good. GroupBy, perhaps, the best way to go. But, why SQL doesn't extend DISTINCT to support multiple words or arbitrary position(only the first field). It should be more clear and friendly

Comment: if you extend the `DISTINCT` to several rows, you will get what you are asking to SQL SERVER: the unique combinations for requested fields.

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT keyword return a unique row like the Following

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM SomeTable
SELECT DISTINCT ID , SCORE FROM SomeTable
```

If you want to get unique value from row try the following code.

**The Below code is copied from [here](http://select%20t.id,%20t.player_name,%20t.team%20from%20tablename%20t%20join%20(select%20team,%20min(id)%20as%20minid%20from%20tablename%20group%20by%20team)%20x%20on%20x.team%20=%20t.team%20and%20x.minid%20=%20t.id)**

```
select t.id, t.player_name, t.team
from tablename t
join (select team, min(id) as minid from tablename group by team) x
on x.team = t.team and x.minid = t.id
```

Comment: So it only works for a single field but not multiple fields?

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(distinct id) uniqueIDCount
from dbo.XXX
```

would count distinct values of `id` field, if you want to count distinct values for field combination you must concat fields, assuming your `id` is integer and `name` is nvarchar:

```
select COUNT(distinct CONVERT(nvarchar, id) + name) uniqueIDCount
from dbo.XXX
```

note that even this way looks nice it is probably not the most efficient one, here you have more efficient, but also more complicated method way:

```
with c as (
    select distinct id, name
    from dbo.XXX
)select COUNT(1)
from c
```

Comment: but if I want to do with **name**? With another COUNT(distinct name)?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's complicated. U can have 3 different queries and u can union to return single set if u want .